# How to distinguish between switching an activity Vs switch to Home Screen in Android

Tags: android, homescreen

I am working on Android:: Media Player Application. The application has 3 activities for simplicity sake:: A, B and C are the activities.

When I am switching from Activity A to B: onPause() and onStop() of Activity A are getting called. But when I go to home screen from Activity A, the same functions: onPause() and onStop() are getting called.

Currently I am facing a problem that: If user goes to home screen:: The settings like outdoor visibility, brightness etc has to be reset to system and on the other hand, If I am switching between the activities, I have to maintain the values as per application specific.

How can I distinguish that, I am switching between the activities of the same application (or) going to home screen.

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution is to detect when the user presses the HOME button. You can do this by overriding the method

```
    onUserLeaveHint()
```

of the Activity Class.

Comment: Isnt this Activtiy Specific callback? And there will be scenarios where in, the application goes to background mode, without user pressing Home key. For example: Media player is running and call comes scenario. I guess in that case the onUserLeaveHint will not be called.

Comment: This doesn't work in 2019. onUserLeaveHint() is sadly called every time when leaving activity (so for example when new activity is launched) - not only when user presses Home button.

Answer (score 0):

You should make these changes every time when activities come to the screen and restore the settings when they disappear from the screen. Activities are supposed to be like separate modules, so it's a good thing to make them less dependent.

This is best done with creating a template activity. Make all the necessary changes in the `onResume()` and `onPause()` methods and derive all other activities from this one. This way your settings management code will be called automatically in every activity.

As for the general application state, you can't really detect whether your application is present on the screen or not because an application in Android is just a bunch of independent components (activities, services, content providers and broadcast receivers). There is no single application with particular visibility states per se. Only activities have it, independently of each other.

Comment: Yes, I am agreeing that it would be good to make them less dependent. But as of now, there are 3 activities and planning to add 2more. And we have to take care of these things for all the new activities. Will there be any way to recognize as an application, that I am in home screen (or) switched to a new application/home screen?

Comment: None that I know off. But this shouldn't be a problem, you can write a template activity which manages everything related to the settings in `onResume()` and `onPause()` and derive other activities from this one. This way you will automatically get the necessary actions in all of your activities.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) to store the app specific settings while your app is in use. And always restore then in onStop()

Comment: Currently I am using SharedPreferences to maintain the setting value and storing/restoring based on when my application in foreground. But there is a possibility that the app can go to background in any activity[A/B/C] - In that case, the code has to be duplicated in onStop() of all the activities. Is there a better way to know that as a whole, the application went to background mode?

Comment: Hmm... the Application class (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html). Does not have such a function, but you could make this setting and getting a common function within your Application and call this within the onStart/onStop of your Activities. You do not need to duplicate the code everywhere.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yeah, we can keep the code in a function and can call the same from all the activities, but only thing is - It is per activity based.

Comment: As I mentioned, at the application level Android does not provide an exit function that we can hook into to restore these values (although you could perhaps set them in the onCreate() of the application).